# ASP ReportViewer Control Rendering >14000 records

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reportviewer

I have been having a problem with `ReportViewer` control when rendering large reports like 14000 records.

The report never opens and i get an error in the console:

```
ServerErrorException: Server returned 500
```

I have tried to render the same data in a `gridview` control and it works. So there is definately a problem with the `ReportViewer` control, but i dont know what that problem is.

**Does anyone have any ideas?**

If this is a common issue with `ReportViewer` Control are there alternative reporting controls that can do the heavy lifting?

Comment: Are you using DataSet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have problem with memory and nothing to do with 14,000 rows or above. Have a look at this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d40124af-b34f-4f5e-a01c-ebce588fb637/out-of-memory-exception-in-report-viewer?forum=vsreportcontrols). In summary, ASP allocates limited memory to the report viewer control.Thus you should consider changing the process and using `Reporting Services` instead of `ReportViewer`.